# NPM: errno ETIMEDOUT

Tags: nodejs, windows, firewall

Hace no mucho, intenté instalar un paquete con Yarn, no pasó de resolver las dependecias que requería el paquete, que intentaba instalar, y me soltó un error. Preferí intentar directamente con NPM, pero poco después me soltó un error que estaba relacionado de cierta forma con el de Yarn. Me decía que el problema se encontraba en mi conexión a internet, pero realmente no era eso, ya que todos los servicios que necesitaban conexión a internet funcionaban. El error que me soltó NPM, junto al de Yarn, fueron los siguientes:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/colors failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1023:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

yarn add v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error Couldn't find package "fsevents@~2.3.2" required by "chokidar@^3.5.1" on the "npm" registry.
```

He intentado aplicar algunas soluciones que he encontrado por la web, que no necesariamente tenían el mismo error que el mío, pero ningúno me ha servido. Tengo sospechas de que está relacionado con el Firewall de Windows. Ya que hace unas horas, inicialicé un proyecto con React; el Firewall de Windows saltó, y recuerdo haberle dado "Allow Access", pero no estoy muy seguro. Me acuerdo que la aplicación que el Firewall bloqueó fue el proceso de NodeJS, pero, después de eso, React siguió funcionando hasta que lo decidí detener. Mi tipo de conexión de red es privada, la tengo configurada de esa manera en el Firewall.

**Ya lo he "solucionado", simplemente reinstalé NodeJS y reinicie mi computadora. Empezó nuevamente a funcionar**